# wxPython: Binding Multiple Widgets to the Same Handler

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have created a huge code and my program is a bit slow,I want to ask if there is a way to bind multiple widgets into the same handler...see below some parts of my code

```
    self.button=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Sensor 1",pos=(10,10),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, self.button)
    self.button.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

    self.button1=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Sensor 2",pos=(110,10),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1, self.button1)
    self.button1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

    self.button2=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Sensor 3",pos=(10,50),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2, self.button2)
    self.button2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

    self.button3=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Sensor 4",pos=(110,50),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton3, self.button3)
    self.button3.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

    self.button4=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Sensor 5",pos=(10,90),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton4, self.button4)
    self.button4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

    self.button5=AB.AquaButton(self,label="OK",pos=(110,142),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton5, self.button5)
    self.button5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

def OnButton(self, event):
    self.new = OtherFrame0()
    self.new.Show()

def OnButton1(self, event):
    self.new = OtherFrame1()
    self.new.Show()

def OnButton2(self, event):
    self.new = OtherFrame2()
    self.new.Show()

def OnButton3(self, event):
    self.new = OtherFrame3()
    self.new.Show()

def OnButton4(self, event):
    self.new = OtherFrame4()
    self.new.Show()

def OnButton5(self, event):
    self.Close()
```

---

```
class OtherFrame0(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Edit Name", size=(210,80),
        style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.CenterOnParent()
    self.SetBackgroundColour('#e4e4e4')

    self.msgTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1,('Sensor 1'),pos=(10,10))

    self.button=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Set",pos=(120,10),size=(85,30))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSendAndClose, self.button)
    self.button.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))


def onSendAndClose(self, event):
    msg0 = self.msgTxt.GetValue()
    Publisher().sendMessage(("show.mainframe0"), msg0)
    sheet1.write(0, 0,msg0)
    book.save('Application.xls')
    self.Close()
```

---

```
    msg = "Sensor 1"
    instructions = wx.StaticText(self,label=msg,pos=(15,53))
    self.pubsubText0 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Sensor 1",
        pos(75,50),style=wx.TE_READONLY)
    self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,value="", pos=(180, 50),
        style=wx.TE_READONLY)
    self.pubsubText0.SetBackgroundColour('#e4e4e4')
```

The last two parts of the code repeated others four times each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can bind multiple widgets to the same handler. You just need to assign a name to each of the widgets or a unique id. I recommend the name because you don't want to accidentally use a system id to one of your widgets. Anyway, I wrote an article that explains it all here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

The main idea is that in the handler you can get the widget from event.GetEventObject(). Then you can grab its name, id, label, etc using the appropriate call: widget.GetId(), widget.GetLabel(), widget.GetName(), etc.